# Un moderador ha borrado mi pregunta. ¿Qué hago?

Tags: soporte, moderación

El moderador [Miquel Coll♦](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7242/miquel-coll) ha borrado mi pregunta auto-respondida.

### El método de borrado.

La pregunta ha sido borrada presumiblemente con privilegios de moderador.
[image: Captura del mensaje de eliminación]
Sin dar ningún motivo para ello.
Esta es una forma destructiva de moderar.
Una moderación constructiva trabajaría con el usuario guiándolo para convertir la pregunta en una que sea apropiada. Esto es lo que sucede con el cerrado de las preguntas, en el cual siempre se da un motivo para el cierre (duplicado, demasiado amplio, no está claro lo que se pregunta, etc). Y es una costumbre generalizada el poner comentarios a los votos negativos para ayudar a los usuarios a corregir errores.
No se qué mecanismos tiene un moderador para enviar un mensaje a un usuario cuando borra una pregunta. Pero como mínimo tiene uno, el correo electrónico que figura en mi perfil.
Quizás el moderador tenía intención de dar un motivo pero le surgió una situación mas importante que requería su atención inmediata. Pensando en esto he sido paciente. Pero ya ha pasado mas de una semana.

### El contenido.

Evidentemente lo considero apropiado, en caso contrario no la hubiese publicado.
No puedo rebatir al moderador pues no ha dado motivo alguno. Con lo que simplemente puedo afirmar que la pregunta es correcta.

- El contenido es pertinente al sitio, pues es una pregunta técnica sobre programación. En el sitio en ingles hay [una pregunta  sobre lo mismo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447095/does-java-monitor-include-instance-variables).
- La forma de redactarla es correcta. La [tercera pregunta mas votada de java en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) tiene un formato similar. En esa pregunta también se expone una opinión técnica y también se da un enlace a alguien que expone una opinión técnica contraria. Y, como en mi pregunta, se pide una explicación sobre qué es lo correcto. La mayor diferencia es que yo incluyo una cita de la opinión técnica contraria; lo cual hago siguiendo la costumbre general de no poner solo un enlace que pueda quedar roto.
- Los comentarios difamatorios sí merecen ser borrados. Pero eso aplica a los comentarios, que no son mios, no a la pregunta.

### ¿Qué hacer?

Es la primera vez en cinco años que me borran una pregunta. Y no estoy muy seguro de qué hacer.
Si el moderador se ha equivocado me gustaría que lo corrija, no pasa nada, todo el mundo tiene derecho a equivocarse.
Si me he equivocado yo me gustaría corregirlo. Para lo cual necesitaría saber qué está mal.

La pregunta en cuestión es : [Si es invocado un método synchronized, ¿únicamente el hilo que lo invoca tiene acceso a la instancia del Objeto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40841/si-es-invocado-un-m%C3%A9todo-synchronized-%C3%BAnicamente-el-hilo-que-lo-invoca-tiene-a?noredirect=1#comment70159_40841)

Captura de pantalla para los que no pueden ver la pregunta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta en cuestión? Sin eso no podemos evaluar el caso.

Comment: Creo recordar la pregunta de la cual hablas. Si no recuerdo mal, aunque el aspecto técnico, claridad, etc. de la pregunta y la respuesta en sí no estaban nada mal, me parece que la pregunta sonaba como a un ataque a la respuesta de otro usuario en una pregunta distinta. Aunque no hay nada mal en publicar una respuesta que contradice la respuesta de otra persona, eso usualmente se hace bajo la misma pregunta. Crear una pregunta separada con el propósito de "humillar" a otra persona (al menos así sonaba), no me parece de buen gusto. Puede que esa sea la razón por la que se borró.

Comment: Puesto que un moderador pregunta cuál es la pregunta entiendo que es correcto enlazarla, y así lo he hecho. @sstan piensa que también es posible que yo sea el que está equivocado. Si es así, el que alguien publique una respuesta a mi pregunta explicando mi error no me humilla sino que me ayuda. No tenía sentido que publicase mi respuesta en la pregunta titulada "Threads - ¿Por qué tener más hilos es mejor?" porque no hubiese sido relevante a esa pregunta.

Comment: Hola Jose. Voy a publicar una respuesta pronto para aclarar la situación pero me gustaría decir con tiempo que debería de haver dejado un comentario y eso es un error mio grave. Pido disculpas por eso. La razón de no dejar comentario es que tras eliminar la publicación no puedo añadir comentarios. Para hacerlo se tiene que reabrir, publicar comentario y volver a eliminar. Aun así eso no es excusa y Pido disculpas. Intento publicar una respuesta detallada hoy. gracias por traerlo en meta (de verdad) :). Un saludo.

Comment: @MiquelColl ¡qué bueno tener moderadores tan dispuestos a la autocrítica! Nótese que los moderadores sí pueden publicar comentarios en las publicaciones borradas, haz la prueba ;)

Comment: @fedorqui tienes razón :/ juro que a veces intento dejar comentarios y el sistema no me deja. No sé en qué situaciones es pero asumí que era para las eliminadas... gracias por el heads up!

Comment: @MiquelColl lo mismo es algo nuevo. Acabo de hacer una prueba y en el sitio que modero yo puedo añadir comentarios incluso en publicaciones eliminadas por otros moderadores o bloqueadas. Lo que sí es más complejo es cuándo recibe notificación el autor de la publicación: si no recuerdo mal, solamente la recibe si quien publica es el moderador que la eliminó y escribe en un intervalo de menos de una hora desde que lo hizo. Pero bueno, eso es otra historia...

Answer (score 5):

Vayamos por partes.

> La pregunta ha sido borrada presumiblemente con privilegios de moderador.

Correcto. Lo borré unilateralmente tras un reporte custom realizado por dos usuarios distintos.

> Sin dar ningún motivo para ello.
>
> Esta es una forma destructiva de moderar.

Estoy de acuerdo. Es un fallo importante por mi parte no haber dejado mensaje alguno en la publicación. No es algo usual en mi y no recuerdo el motivo por el cual no lo hice, pero garantizo que voy a dejar siempre un comentario cuando me encuentre en estas situaciones.

> No puedo rebatir al moderador pues no ha dado motivo alguno. Con lo que simplemente puedo afirmar que la pregunta es correcta.

Desde mi punto de vista y el de otros 2 usuarios que la vieron (mas 4 downvotes que se lanzaron antes de que la borrara), esta pregunta no estaba bien realizada. En concreto, el contenido de la pregunta y respuesta buscaba rebatir otra [respuesta realizada por Elenasys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4923/7242).

El motivo de la eliminación es simple:

- Si se quiere rebatir una respuesta de otro usuario, se debe hacer en los comentarios/chat específico de esa respuesta.
- Si la explicación para rebatir la respuesta es demasiado extensa, lo ideal es añadir una respuesta en esa misma pregunta explicando por qué esa solución es incorrecta y proponiendo la solución correcta.

En este caso concreto, no estabas preguntando *por qué* no era correcto, sino que ya tenías la respuesta. Eso indica que podrías haber publicado esa respuesta directamente en la pregunta.

Otra cosa sería que quisieras saber por qué esa respuesta funciona o no de una manera generalizada, pero la pregunta que hiciste era específica de esa respuesta.

Quizá la pregunta sería válida si no buscara desacreditar otra respuesta de manera específica y se hubiera preguntado de manera genérica y a posteriori añadir un simple comentario a la respuesta inicial para indicar que eso es incorrecto enlazando a la nueva respuesta.

Comment: La pregunta a la que responde ElenaSys es "Threads - ¿Por qué tener más hilos es mejor?". ¿Me estás diciendo que ponga en esa pregunta una repuesta explicando que un método synchronized no hace que otro hilo accediendo a la instancia del objeto tenga que esperar? Por supuesto que no, eso no responde a la pregunta, es otro tema. Con lo que ya solo queda la cuestión del supuesto descrédito. ¿Cómo edito mi pregunta para que no la consideres desacreditante? ¿Valdría "<mismo_título> He leido <texto_citado> ¿Es cierto?" ? No se puede desacreditar a quien no se nombra.

Comment: Creo que todos los puntos que menciona Miquel son adecuados

Comment: Entonces, ¿estaría bien así?

Comment: Sí :) pregunta reabierta !

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos gracias por realizar los cambios. He realizado una edicion menor para darle un bump y le he dado positivo por que ahora es una pregunta de calidad!